# jquery-ui slider(): How to get an always equal value between handles

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

Have this self-made slider: http://jsfiddle.net/wyc3P/4/
What it does: takes min and max values *in seconds* and converts them to a *minute:second* format during slide.

Goal is to set maximum value between handles to be exactly 40 seconds.

I thought it worked fine, until I moved right handle to match 1:00 - 1:40, but it showed 1:00 - 1:41 instead. However if you then move left handle all the way to the left, it shows correctly 0:00 - 0:40.

Please help to resolve coding mistakes. =)

Comment: Do you mean the *maximum* value between handles to be exactly 40 seconds?

Comment: @pjumble: yes, sorry, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sliders are actually staying 40 apart (maximum), the problem is your minute/second calculations underneath use the original `ui` values passed in to the function, even if you set a new value:

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
    if ((ui.values[1]-ui.values[0]) > 40) {
        var index = $(ui.handle).index();
        if (index === 1) {
            // You're setting a new slider position here, but ui.values[1] still contains the old position
            $('#slider').slider('values', 1, ui.values[0]+40);
        } else if (index === 2) {
            $('#slider').slider('values', 0, ui.values[1]-40);
        }
    }

    // your calculations use the original ui values
}
```

You would need to update the `ui.values` too:

```
    if ((ui.values[1]-ui.values[0]) > 40) {
        var index = $(ui.handle).index();
        if (index === 1) {
            ui.values[1] = ui.values[0] + 40;
            $('#slider').slider('values', 1, ui.values[1]);
        } else if (index === 2) {
            ui.values[0] = ui.values[1] - 40;
            $('#slider').slider('values', 0, ui.values[0]);
        }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wyc3P/8/

Comment: Sure thing. I guess it's a weather issue. =)